# Multi-monitor setup, only terminal on one monitor

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, gui

I currently have three monitors hooked up to my computer. I was just wondering if it is possible to have two monitors use the window manager - so, GUI - and have a single monitor not using the GUI but only command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and move it on which monitor do you wish. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to put terminal in full-screen mode, and voilà: you have only the terminal on that monitor.

Otherwise, I think that you can do it using virtualization. But only for this purpose it seems without sense.